# How to create probability density chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe `data` (in my real dataset I have much more data):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = pd.read_table(StringIO("""time_diff  avg_trips_per_day
631         1.0
231         1.0
431         1.0
7031        1.0
17231       1.0
20000       20.0
21000       15.0
22000       10.0"""), delim_whitespace=True)
```

In order to see the distribution of the values of `time_diff`, I create this barplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
data['timegroup'] = pd.qcut(data['time_diff'], 150)
sns.barplot(x='timegroup', y='avg_trips_per_day', data=data, estimator=sum)
```

It takes the values of `avg_trips_per_day` for each bin (`timegroup`) and calculates a sum of `avg_trips_per_day`.

My result looks as follows:

[image]

So, it's indeed not the best visualization for my data. I think that the probability density plot would be a better fit. In the X axis I would like to see the values of `avg_trips_per_day`, while the Y axis should contain probabilities.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can use distplot `sns.distplot(data['avg_trips_per_day'])`  by default it draws both a histogram and a kernel density estimator but you can tweak it by `kde=False`  or `histogram=False`

Comment: There's no `timegroup` column in your dataframe. You have probably missed out on a few lines of code

Comment: @ClockSlave: Sorry, forget to add one line of code. Please see my update.

Comment: @ayhan: If I do `data["time_diff"].unique()`, I see the lowest value equal to 200 in my real dataset. But `distplot` X axis contains other values. like 0.0, 0.1. Do you know why this may happen? P.S. Indeed I need a `displot` for `time_diff`, not `avg_trips_per_day`.

Comment: unique doesn't return a sorted list. Can you try with `data["time_diff"].min()`?